# How to toggle fullscreen when F11 pressed in glfw c++

Tags: c++, glfw

I can't get fullscreen to work while pressing F11 like other game in glfw.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

void key_input(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_F11 && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        if (!glfwGetPrimaryMonitor())
            glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
        if (glfwGetPrimaryMonitor())
            !glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the answer is but calling `glfwGetPrimaryMonitor` isn't likely to do anything, inverting its result will do even less

Comment: A quick Google suggests [glfwSetWindowMonitor](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga81c76c418af80a1cce7055bccb0ae0a7) is what you need

Answer (score 1):

You know, what [glfwGetPrimaryMonitor](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__monitor.html#gac3adb24947eb709e1874028272e5dfc5) is doing:

> This function returns the primary monitor. This is usually the monitor where elements like the task bar or global menu bar are located.

What you want is a fullscreen window:

> **[Full screen windows](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_full_screen)**
>
> To create a full screen window, you need to specify which monitor the window should use. In most cases, the user's primary monitor is a good choice.
>
> Windowed mode windows can be made full screen by setting a monitor with [glfwSetWindowMonitor](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga81c76c418af80a1cce7055bccb0ae0a7), and full screen ones can be made windowed by unsetting it with the same function.

**Be aware:** `glfwSetWindowMonitor` can only be called from the main thread (and not from within a callback). Therefore, you have to set a flag in the callback and check in the main thread, if that flag was set or unset.